# Change directory in Docker Terminal Windows

Tags: docker, eclipse-hono

I just installed Docker Toolbox for getting started with Eclipse Hono on Windows 7 64bit. 
Unfortunately the eclipse Hono directory is in C:\User\Desktop 
My docker is always using the directory Z

How can I can access C directory in the docker terminal? 
I tried

> cd C:\User\Desktop

but it did not work, the docker terminal says

> No such file or directory

So my problem is I can't get out of directory Z. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try `cd /c/Users/....` .